# Elasticsearch/ Searchkick gem - boosting fields do not return results with special characters (e.g. apostrophes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, elasticsearch, searchkick, boosting

We're using the [searchkick gem](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) in our app and have many documents with fields that contains special characters such as apostrophes, e.g. an offer with the `title` `Valentine's Day Special`.

Without boosters, a search for `Valentines` or `Valentine's` or `Valentine` would return the correct search results:

```
Activity.search "Valentines"
```

However when boosters for those the title field is incorporated, a search of any of the above queries will not return the `Valentine's Day Special` result.

```
Activity.search "Valentines", fields: ["title^10"]
```

I've been trying to troubleshoot through the Elasticsearch/ Searckick documentation but haven't found a solution yet. Anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this with a partial work match workaround:

```
Offer.search("Valentine's", fields: ["name"], match: :word_middle)
```